# Python: redirect text parsing output to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a simple script which will parse a text file of mine.
Pattern is the following:

```
0.061024 seconds for Process 0 to send.
0.060062 seconds for Process 1 to receive.
```

This goes on in a loop.

The python file looks like this:

```
import fileinput, csv

data = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    time, sep, status = line.partition("seconds")
    if sep:
    print(time.strip())
with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
w = csv.writer(f)
w.writerow('send receive'.split())
w.writerows(data)
```

this gives me the desired output on the bash and also creates two columns with the send and receive. How do I fill them with input which is printed by

```
print(time.strip())
```

I would like to have this output in a CSV file in two columns.

how shall I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`writer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) function that comes with the `csv` module:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    cwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for var in list_of_values:
        cwriter.writerow(var)
```

This takes into consideration, that you have all the rows as separate lists within `list_of_values`, as in:

```
list_of_values = [['col1', 'col2'],['col1', 'col2']]
```

Comment: Thanks Games Brainiac. your list_of_values writes the elements in one column, I would like to have the send time in one column and then the receive time in another one. In the end I still dont get the expected output into the CSV :(

Comment: @user2937795 Then you need to make your question clearer. Otherwise, people will have a hard time giving you an answer.

Comment: I want to parse the time and then, input these values into two columns . one for the send and the other for receive. As they are in a continious change they shall be written into these columns one after another so the separation will happen, but i downt know how to write all these time values into the csv